# How to theme title field

Tags: 7, theming, nodes, panels

Normally when I theme a field, I use a template suggestion in format `field--fieldname--contenttype`.  However, it doesn't seem to be possible to do this with the node title.  I've tried both of the following template suggestions:

```
field--title--contenttype.tpl.php
field--field-title--contenttype.tpl.php
```

Neither of them work (I've cleared caches).  The title isn't technically a field, since it's more like a property on the node object, so that may be the problem?

Is there any way to theme the title field?  It feels like I'm missing something simple.

N.b. I'm using panels and have dropped the node title pane into the panel but need to theme it differently.

Comment: http://www.webomelette.com/how-to-theme-fields-drupal-7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [Title](https://www.drupal.org/project/title) module to convert your title to a proper field. Following that, your template file should work.

Comment: Very cool, I will check it out.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks! After converting the title to a field via the manage fields page on the content type, I was able to template the field using `field--title-field--mycontenttype.tpl.php`

Comment: Great to hear, Title is an epic module!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just edit the css file?
    #content h1 {
      color: blue;
    }
Something like this.
Node title is wrapped in content div and it is  or 
You may check your page.tpl.php

Comment: I need to change the HTML structure as oppose to just the colour